# BEiT large example on Huggingface raises warnings

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, warnings, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I run the example code found at: https://huggingface.co/microsoft/beit-large-patch16-512 of the BEiT (large-sized model, fine-tuned on ImageNet-1k), with no changes:

```
from transformers import BeitFeatureExtractor, BeitForImageClassification
from PIL import Image
import requests
url = 'http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg'
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
feature_extractor = BeitFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained('microsoft/beit-large-patch16-512')
model = BeitForImageClassification.from_pretrained('microsoft/beit-large-patch16-512')
inputs = feature_extractor(images=image, return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)
logits = outputs.logits
# model predicts one of the 1000 ImageNet classes
predicted_class_idx = logits.argmax(-1).item()
print("Predicted class:", model.config.id2label[predicted_class_idx])
```

The code runs correctly but it raises the following warnings:

```
/home/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/functional.py:568: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1646755853042/work/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:2228.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
    /home/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py:158: UserWarning: Creating a tensor from a list of numpy.ndarrays is extremely slow.
Please consider converting the list to a single numpy.ndarray with numpy.array() before converting to a tensor.
(Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1646755853042/work/torch/csrc/utils/tensor_new.cpp:210.)
```

Are these warnings safe to ignore? If not how to fix them? Should I just signal this as a bug on the Huggingface page?

Comment: That was already fixed with PR [#14306](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/14306).

Comment: @cronoik thanks a lot, probably I had an outdated library, the other warning is still unfixed maybe? `/home/name/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/functional.py:568: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at  /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1646755853042/work/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:2228.)`

Comment: Yes, that is still unfixed. Not sure if someone is already working on it.